# PyCUDA/CUDA: Causes of non-deterministic launch failures?

Tags: python, cuda, gpgpu, pycuda

Anyone following CUDA will probably have seen a few of my queries regarding a project I'm involved in, but for those who haven't I'll summarize. (Sorry for the long question in advance)

Three Kernels, One Generates a data set based on some input variables (deals with bit-combinations so can grow exponentially), another solves these generated linear systems, and another reduction kernel to get the final result out. These three kernels are ran over and over again as part of an optimisation algorithm for a particular system.

On my dev machine (Geforce 9800GT, running under CUDA 4.0) this works  perfectly, all the time, no matter what I throw at it (up to a computational limit based on the stated exponential nature), but on a test machine (4xTesla S1070's, only one used, under CUDA 3.1) the exact same code (Python base, PyCUDA interface to CUDA kernels), produces the exact results for 'small' cases, but in mid-range cases, the solving stage fails on random iterations.

Previous problems I've had with this code have been to do with the numeric instability of the problem, and have been deterministic in nature (i.e fails at exactly the same stage every time), but this one is frankly pissing me off, as it will fail whenever it wants to.

As such, I don't have a reliable way to breaking the CUDA code out from the Python framework and doing proper debugging, and PyCUDA's debugger support is questionable to say the least.

I've checked the usual things like pre-kernel-invocation checking of free memory on the device, and occupation calculations say that the grid and block allocations are fine. I'm not doing any crazy 4.0 specific stuff, I'm freeing everything I allocate on the device at each iteration and I've fixed all the data types as being floats.

**TL;DR**, Has anyone come across any gotchas regarding CUDA 3.1 that I haven't seen in the release notes, or any issues with PyCUDA's autoinit memory management environment that would cause intermittent launch failures on repeated invocations?

Comment: The short answer is no. PyCUDA autoinit is really just a context establishment and release mechanism, it doesn't do anything magical. All I can recommend is making sure you have plenty of error checking around all of your kernels. It might also be worth having a look at the PTX generated by the two compilers and see if they are radically different. The offer to test you code on some other hardware still stands, if you are interested.

Comment: The only time I had seemingly random kernel failures, the problem was a bug that caused negative indexes. It only manifested itself when cudaMalloc assigned 0x0 to the relevant pointer, which was not consistent. good luck...

Comment: I'm leaving this question up as it deals with the differences between 3.1 and 4.0; I cannot replicate the failures I see in 3.1 on 4.0 and no reasonable explanation has appeared. If anyone has come across this question looking for an answer; Upgrade to 4.0

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
cuda-memcheck python yourapp.py
```

You likely have an out of bounds memory access.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nVidia CUDA Profiler and see what gets executed before the failure.

Comment: Actually, you can't. The profiler relies on each kernel exiting normally, and then the thread hosting the GPU context also exiting normally, before it is guaranteed to flush the driver internal counters which are used to record profiling data. If you code aborts abnormally, the context is usually destroyed prematurely, and the unflushed profiling data is lost.

Comment: "Usually destroyed" sounds like give it a shot?